# Changing value of maskable not taking immediate effect unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm busy with a project on unity that has some components inside a parent that has a mask.

I'm able to drag these components and place them where need be. The issue is when I need to drag them out of the parent component they dissapear because of the mask.

My soultuon to this was to then turn the maskable variable off for the component currently being dragged.

My issue though is that when it is turned off the mask still functions as if it were on. However of I manually turn it off through the inspector then the mask doesn't effect it anymore.

Could someone please tell me what they think should be done to make it take effect right away

Comment: You mean on runtime or in the editor/SceneView?

Comment: @derHugo, I'm changing that value with code during runtime. So I need it to immediately take effect during runtime